# Core data migration - how to combine two entities into one

Tags: ios, core-data, core-data-migration

I have a old core data model with two entities:

**First entity**

FirstString has an attribute: string1 which is NSString

**Second entity**

SecondString has an attribute: string2 which is NSString

They have a one to many relationship: first entity <--->> second entity.

The new entity - "ComboEntity" - has one to one relationship with both first entity and second entity.

Now I have new core data model with new entity

**ComboEntity** has an attribute: fullString

Question:

**How do I migrate the data and combine string 1 and string 2 into fullString?**

Thanks!

Comment: I recently did this using a custom NSEntityMigrationPolicy.  I'll work on posting the solution if you're still interested.

Comment: @bentford, how did you do this?

Comment: hey @bentford too bad you never posted your answer ;(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a custom mapping policy.

1. Create a mapping model from old entity version to new entity version
2. Change your code to use custom mapping policy instead of automatic
3. Write a custom mapping policy class, see example below:

---

```
@interface FullStringFromTwoStringsMappingPolicy : NSEntityMigrationPolicy

- (NSString *)fullStringForMyEntity:(MyEntity *)myEntity;

@end

@implementation FullStringFromTwoStringsMappingPolicy

- (NSString *)fullStringForMyEntity:(MyEntity *)myEntity
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", myEntity.string1, myEntity.string2];
}

@end
```

In your mapping model you write a value expression as shown in the screenshot. Instead of contactHashMD5 you'd have your fullString attribute instead.

[image]

Best regards,

sven.

Comment: Thanks svena for quick answer. This is what I was looking for. But how would I go about doing this as I have two different entities from which I have to combine. Your answer addresses a situation for one entity to another. Thanks!

Comment: Indeed, I didn't read your question carefully enough. Your scenario is a kind I have not tested before. How is the first entity tied to the other entity?

Comment: first and second entities have one to many relationship. first entity <-->> second entity. The comboEntity has one to one relationship with both the first and second.

Answer (score 0):

CoreData model versioning has extensive support on iOS. Basically you need to create a new *version* of your model and create the new entity in that (possibly leaving also the old entities). Then, depending on your need, you can choose different levels of migration support from the framework, starting from "lightweight migration" that simple fills the new fields with nil, until "custom entity migration policies" that allows you to define callback functions that will do migration process of arbitrary complexity. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html).

In your case you could do the migration also manually, checking at every application start (or just once) whether the model is converted already, and if not, run a loop that fills the new entity based on the old ones.

Comment: MrTJ, I read the docs and I feel comfortable doing manual migration from one entity to another. But in my situation I have two different entities that I need to combine to populate a new entity. An example of call back function with two entities would be of great help. Thanks.

Comment: You should have the information which string1 instance you have to combine with a particular string2. What you do here is analogous to *JOIN* in database sense. So you iterate through the entity that serves as a key in the scenario (and get your functions being called back) and from the callback you open the instance of the other entity that corresponds to your "key".