# Combine two fields into one during core data migration

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data-migration

I have two versions of my core data model with different entities

I've built a mappingmodel to translate from the old model to the new model which works for 1 to 1 mappings

I'd like to combine (concatenate) two fields from the old model into a single field in the new model. Eg something similar to:

```
newmodel.user.name = oldmodel.user.firstname + " " + oldmodel.user.lastname
```

How should I go about this?

Comment: I think this question is very interesting and googled about it. I´ve found the following posted by sven here , that may help u. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9580274/core-data-migration-how-to-combine-two-entities-into-one